# Telegram Bot DeleteMessage ID with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small VBA Excel code where I send messages each 10 seconds through a certain bot however each time I send a new message I want to delete the previous message.

I have the code to send messages however I don't know the procedure to delete messages through vba Excel.

```
Sub SendTelegramDeleteId()

Dim objRequest As Object
Dim strChatId As String
Dim strMessage As String
Dim strPostData As String
Dim strResponse As String

 strChatId = "**********" 
 strMessage = "Last check: " & TimeValue(Now)

strPostData = "chat_id=" & strChatId & "&text=" & strMessage

 Set objRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    With objRequest
  .Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/MYBOT/sendMessage?", False
  .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
  .Send (strPostData)
   GetMessageId = .responsetext


  .Open "POST", "https://api.telegram.org/MyBOT/deleteMessage?chat_id=*********&message_id=11605", True

End With

End Sub
```

The part with the deletemessage does not work. Can anyone help?

Comment: Please note that *"does not work"* is no usefull error description and [“Can someone help me?” is not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/3219613). We need to know where exactly your issues and difficulties are, which errors you get and where and what you expected vs what your code actually did. • Reading [mcve] might also help to improve your question.

Comment: Apologies, first time i pose a question in this forum. The code sends the message but I am not able to delete the previous sent message. The complete example is the code I posted. Last code line does not work.